# How to add a CPU to win 2003 serv

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, windows-server-2003

I added a cpu to my vm 2003. I needed an instruction how to set up new processor affinity to my serv win 2003

Comment: More information about the system is required. You shouldn't have to set processor affinity it should be automatic.  By default Windows will use every processor and core it can use for a given process, the process itself might take advantage of that fact, but doesn't change its automatic.

Comment: In device list of my machine i see a newly added cpu as device. But task manager didn't display a second cpu nor assign a processus too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the HAL for your VM is set to a uniprocessor configuration. You can "upgrade" it to a multiprocessor HAL fairly easily though. Download the [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) utility, and place the extracted executable in the same directory as this script (save it as mphal-upgrade.bat):

```
@echo off
@title "Upgrading to ACPI Multi-Processor HAL.."
cls
echo ====================================================
echo Upgrading to ACPI Multi-Processor HAL..
echo ====================================================
echo.
echo please wait..
devcon sethwid @ROOT\PCI_HAL\0000 := !E_ISA_UP !ACPIPIC_UP !ACPIAPIC_UP !ACPIAPIC_MP !MPS_UP !MPS_MP !SGI_MPS_MP !SYSPRO_MP !SGI_MPS_MP > nul
devcon sethwid @ROOT\ACPI_HAL\0000 := !E_ISA_UP !ACPIPIC_UP !ACPIAPIC_UP !ACPIAPIC_MP !MPS_UP !MPS_MP !SGI_MPS_MP !SYSPRO_MP !SGI_MPS_MP > nul
devcon sethwid @ROOT\PCI_HAL\0000 := +ACPIAPIC_MP > nul
devcon sethwid @ROOT\ACPI_HAL\0000 := +ACPIAPIC_MP > nul
devcon update %windir%\inf\hal.inf ACPIAPIC_MP > nul
echo.
echo ====================================================
echo Script Completed: press any key to reboot..
echo ====================================================
pause > nul
devcon reboot
```

After rebooting you should be able to open the Device Manager, expand the Computer entry and see that the ACPI Multiprocessor HAL device is loaded correctly. The Task Manager should also show that you now have two CPUs available.

Credit for script: http://www.pimp-my-rig.com/2008/08/article-acpi-uniprocessor-to.html